My project stopped adding, updating and deleting (Spring + MongoDB)
I have a project using SpringBoot and MongoDB. At some point it stopped working and is showing the following logs:
2024-05-22T11:50:26.046-03:00 2024-05-22T11:50:26.048-03:00
2024-05-22T11:50:26.075-03:00
INFO 21084
[ restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode [ restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate: Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
INFO 21084 INFO 21084 [ restartedMain] RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport: Spring Data JPA - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface c ries.HistoricRepository; If you want this repository to be a JPA repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: jakarta.persistence.Entity, jakarta.persistence.MappedSupercla ider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
2024-05-22T11:50:26.076-03:00 INFO 21084 --- [ restartedMain] RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport: Spring Data JPA - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface c ries.MachineRepository; If you want this repository to be a JPA repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: jakarta.persistence.Entity, jakarta.persistence.MappedSuperclas der extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository

In my head it doesn't make any sense because I didn't make any changes to the model or repository structures.
model:
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import Lombok.ALLArgsConstructor;
import Lombok.Data;
import Lombok. NoArgsConstructor;
import
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
@Document(collection = "products")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Product {
  public interface CreateProduct {
  }
  public interface UpdateProduct {
  }
@Id
private String id;

@NotBlank
private String name;

private String image;
}

Repository:
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends MongoRepository<Product, String> {
  Product findByName(String name);
}

I have the following properties:

src > main > resources > application-dev.properties
spring.output.ansi.enabled=always

# DATASOURCE
spring.data.mongodb.uri-mongodb://localhost:27017/db_project
# H2 CLIENT
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
9 # JPA, SQL
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.mongodb.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MongoDBDialect
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true




src > main > resources > application.properties

spring.output.ansi.enabled=always
spring.profiles.active=dev
security.jwt.secret-key=3cfa76ef14937c
# 1h in millisecond
8 security.jwt.expiration-time=36000

What could be causing this? I don't know what I did to make it stop working, especially since it was working until yesterday.
I tried modifying the properties, adding some tags like "@EnableMongoRepositories" in the main file, but nothing is working.
I hope the program starts adding, updating and deleting products again, because in my mind it doesn't make sense for it to suddenly stop working (I just changed the service of an object).

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question. Read: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Format your code and make use of block quotes ```like this```.
